# MVC2とMVC3移行でquerystringに危険なコードが入力された場合の挙動が異なる

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

MVC2（aspx）でquerystringに危険なコードが埋め込まれた場合は以下のエラーが発生します。

```
System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: 危険な可能性のある Request.QueryString 値がクライアント (="...T 1,NULL,'<script>alert("XSS")...") から検出されました。
```

MVC3（razor）でquerystringに危険なコードが埋め込まれた場合の挙動は何も起きません（部分ビューがない画面のみ（以下参照））。
cshtmlに「@Html.Partial("aaaaaaaa")」が含まれているとHttpRequestValidat‌​ionException発生（以下のエラーが発生）」

```
{"ハンドラー System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper の子の要求を実行中にエラーが発生しました。"}
```

なぜ動作が違うのか原因がわかりません。
ご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC3以降はベースとなるASP.NET及び.NET Frameworkが4系に移行しています。この影響で、MVC2とMVC3とでバリデーション方法が異なります。`web.confing`にて[`httpRuntime`要素の`requestValidationMode`属性](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/e1f13641(v=vs.110).aspx)で動作を制御できます。

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

の設定を行うことで従来互換のバリデーションに変更できます。
（完全に同じ動作をするかどうかは把握していません。）

挙動が異なるだけでバリデーションが行われていないわけではないので、セキュリティを考慮すれば、無理に古いバリデーション方法を指定すべきではないと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！！requestValidationModeを指定しても挙動が変わりませんでした。Frameworkの移行によって若干の挙動が変わることがわかりました。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

現在の.NET Frameworkの実装では`HttpRequestValidat‌​ionException`は実際に問題のあるパラメーターにアクセスした場合に発生します。ですので条件は大別して

- `RouteCollection`のパターンに登録されている
- アクションの引数として定義されている
- `Request.Params[key]`や`Request.QueryString[key]`で値を読み出す

のいずれかになります。

ですのでパラメーターを直接読みだしている場合は処理フローにより例外が発生しないこともあり得ます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！！MVC2ではパラメータにアクセスしなくても「HttpRequestValidat‌​ionException」が発生するという認識で大丈夫ですかね？「すべてのパラメーターを部分ビューのためにコピーしており」←勉強になりました！ありがとうございました！